# Merge more than two data frames at once

Tags: r

I need extract the common part of a data in a big table. To simplify the explanation, I created a table below. what I need, is to keep only those rows  which variable value ID  is common to all of them. In this case, the common variable is ID=2

```
dt<-data.table( YEAR = c("2001", "2000", "2001", "2001","1999", "2000", "2000", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "2001"),
                ID = c("2","2","2","1","1","3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "1"),
                Var1 =sample(0:500, 12, rep=TRUE),
                Var2 =sample(0:500, 12, rep=TRUE)

 )
dt
```

The outcome should look like:

```
 dt2<-data.frame  (YEAR = c("1999", "2000", "2001", "2001"),
                   ID = c("2","2","2","2"),
                   Var1 =c("49", "335", "27", "149"),
                   Var2 =c ("195", "4", "393", "390"))

 dt2
```

What I have tried so far was actualy to subset the data based on each year, create a data frame for each and then apply an inner join. The solution is not really nice and not feasible for big tables where I would have ten years. 
Any idea on how can I get it faster and/or nicer?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` to find the `intersect`, i.e.

```
Reduce(intersect, split(dt$ID, dt$YEAR))
#[1] "2"
```

To use it to subset your data table,

```
dt[dt$ID %in% Reduce(intersect, split(dt$ID, dt$YEAR))]

#   YEAR ID Var1 Var2
#1: 2001  2  135  339
#2: 2000  2  449   25
#3: 2001  2  108  394
#4: 1999  2  143   94
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this sausage

```
subset(dt,ID%in%which(apply(table(dt$YEAR,dt$ID),2,function(x){all(x>0)})))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
uniqueYears <- unique(dt$YEAR)
dt[, .SD[all(uniqueYears %in% YEAR)], by = ID]

   ID YEAR Var1 Var2
1:  2 2001  178  445
2:  2 2000  219  299
3:  2 2001  121   10
4:  2 1999  235  109
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Count how often a given ID over the years; select those IDS that occur in 
# most years (this could be more than one)
sel <- dt[ , .(nyears = length(unique(YEAR))), by = ID][nyears == max(nyears), ]

# It could be possible that there is not ID that is present in all years; give
# an warning if this happens 
if (length(unique(dt$YEAR)) != sel$nyears[1]) {
  warning("Selected ID not present in all years.")
}

# Select those records with the selected ID's 
result <- dt[ID %in% sel$ID, ]
```